# How to implement method with params with AutoBean?

Tags: java, gwt, autobean

I have the following Interface :

```
public interface beanExample {
   public BigDecimal norm(BigDecimal dec);
}
```

and then i create a Category for it:

```
public class beanExampleCategory {

   public static BigDecimal norm(BigDecimal dec) {
    return dec != null ? dec : BigDecimal.ZERO;
   }
}
```

and my Factory looks like :

```
@Category(beanExampleCategory.class)
public interface myFactory extends AutoBeanFactory { 
   AutoBean<beanExample> mybean();
}
```

But when i compile i got those errors:

```
[ERROR] The beanExample parameterization is not simple 
 and the following methods did not have static implementations:
[ERROR] public abstract java.math.BigDecimal norm(java.math.BigDecimal dec)
[ERROR] Unable to complete due to previous errors
```

I try to resolve into several ways but i cant figure out how to solve it!

How can i implement a method with params with AutoBean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your category method has to take an `AutoBean<beanExample>` as its first argument.

See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#Categories